# How to fix focus problem on SVG image with CSS

Tags: html, css, vue.js, svg, focus

I have Svg image, that is the outer layer, and inside I have other divs and then text  which I have fixed with positioning. My hover and other effects works fine, but when I try to add focus,then it works but having too much space around. Right now it looks like this ( below image) when I tab ( keyboard) on my Element.

[image]

My Code:

```
<template>
  <div class="markar-container">
    <button class="btn-focus" @focus="true", @blur="false">
      <div class="markar-items">
        <UnionIcon class="union-layer" /> // this is the svg image I have imported 
        <div class="color-layer">
          <div class="text">AA</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

// My CSS styling:


.markar-items {
  position: relative;
}

.union-layer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.color-layer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: #3ac371;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 16px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 13px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-focus:focus .union-layer {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 3px;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
  outline: none;
}

.btn-focus:focus .color-layer {
  background: #9f1853;
}

// also tried targetting the svg selector, but didnot help
.btn-focus:focus > svg.dl-svg-path {
  border-style: dashed;
  outline: none;
}
```

// How can I achieve the below, the border-styles dashed around the white circle:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track, but the CSS selectors and the properties are not correct. So, the focus (and hover) on the button is good and will work out fine. The CSS selector needs to be "anywhere in the tree", so just a space between the `.btn-focus:focus` and the `circle.dot`.

For the dotted stroke on the `<circle>` you need the `stroke-dasharray`.

Original code:

```css
h1 {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.markar-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.markar-items {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.btn-focus:hover circle.dot,
.btn-focus:focus circle.dot {
  fill: #9f1853;
}

.btn-focus:hover circle.outline,
.btn-focus:focus circle.outline {
  stroke-dasharray: 1;
}

text {
  pointer-events: none;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Just here to get focus" />
<div class="markar-container">
  <button class="btn-focus">
      <h1>Pin</h1>
      <div class="markar-items">
        <svg width="70" height="70" viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="display: block;">
          <rect width="10" height="10" fill="yellow"/>
          <circle class="outline" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" fill="white" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".3" />
          <circle class="dot" cx="5" cy="5" r="3.5" fill="green" />
          <text font-size="4" fill="white" x="5" y="5" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">AA</text>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

### Update

How to use `:active`: Styles applied on `:active` can/will override styles defined in `:hover` and `:focus`. In the case of the `stroke-dasharray` you can give it another value or simply set it to `none`:

```css
h1 {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.markar-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.markar-items {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.btn-focus:hover circle.dot,
.btn-focus:focus circle.dot {
  fill: #9f1853;
}

.btn-focus:hover circle.outline,
.btn-focus:focus circle.outline {
  stroke-dasharray: 1;
}

.btn-focus:active circle.dot {
  fill: lime;
}

.btn-focus:active circle.outline {
  stroke-dasharray: none; /* override style on :focus and :hover*/
  stroke: black;
}

text {
  pointer-events: none;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Just here to get focus" />
<div class="markar-container">
  <button class="btn-focus">
      <h1>Pin</h1>
      <div class="markar-items">
        <svg width="70" height="70" viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="display: block;">
          <rect width="10" height="10" fill="yellow"/>
          <circle class="outline" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" fill="white" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".3" />
          <circle class="dot" cx="5" cy="5" r="3.5" fill="green" />
          <text font-size="4" fill="white" x="5" y="5" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">AA</text>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </button>
</div>
```